# How to count scatterplot observations on geoJSON?

Tags: python, dataframe, count, geojson, geopandas

Basically, I have a municipality map of the Netherlands with a scatter plot of knotweed observations, using PySpark and Python. What I now want to know, is the count of knotweed observations per municipality. Below the code I have now:

```
import ... 

map_source = 'https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbsgebiedsindelingen/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typeName=cbs_gemeente_2017_gegeneraliseerd&outputFormat=json'

#resize the map to the correct coordinate system (Amersfoort RD/New; 28992)
gdf = gpd.read_file(map_source)
epsg_code = 28992
gdf.crs = {"init": "epsg:{}".format(epsg_code)}
gdf_reprojected = gdf.to_crs({"init": "epsg:4326"})

import json
the_json = json.loads(gdf_reprojected.to_json())

#Convert to String like object.
json_data = json.dumps(the_json)

from bokeh...

geosource = GeoJSONDataSource(geojson = json_data)

q = figure(title = 'Knotweed observations', plot_height = 700 , plot_width = 700, toolbar_location = None, )

q.patches('xs','ys', source = geosource,fill_color = {'field' :'per_cent_year', 'transform' : color_mapper},
line_color = 'black', line_width = 0.25, fill_alpha = 1)

#creating latitude and longitude points from dataframe as list
latlist = datadf.select('Lat').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()
lonlist = datadf.select('Lon').rdd.flatMap(lambda x: x).collect()

#adding these points to the map using the lists
q.scatter(lonlist,latlist, size = 0.5, marker='^')
output_notebook()
#Display figure.
show(q)
```

Forgive me if you shake your head at this, I am not a star at coding.

I removed some code that is not important for you to know. Not all this code is maybe still necessary, but I left this in just in case it is. This code gives me a nice map of the Netherlands with a scatter plot of knotweed observations, so that is correct. Datadf is our dataframe in which all the points are stored. As you can see, I had to resize the coordinate system of the municipality map, I hope if that is not a problem. The link can be clicked of the datasource, to see how it is set up. Here is the link again again: https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbsgebiedsindelingen/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typeName=cbs_gemeente_2017_gegeneraliseerd&outputFormat=json

Our points (the observations) are normal latitude longitude coordinates.

What I imagine that I use a Python function to check in what municipality the observation is, then store the count using a for loop for example. However, as you can see clicking the link, originally the geoJSON does not use latitude and longitude values, so this might be a problem? Also, for this I need to retrieve the data from the geoJSON (what coordinates are for what municipalities and etc.), and I must say I don't exactly know how.

In what way can I check the count of observations per municipality? I currently do not know/how I go about. Or is that doable at all? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

- a simple way to find the counts is to do a *spatial join* then aggregate (count) number of points (observations)
- you did not provide any sample data of observations, so I have generated to demonstrate the technique
- have used **plotly** to demonstrate visualisation - color region based on count of observations

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.express as px
import shapely.geometry

map_source = "https://geodata.nationaalgeoregister.nl/cbsgebiedsindelingen/wfs?request=GetFeature&service=WFS&version=2.0.0&typeName=cbs_gemeente_2017_gegeneraliseerd&outputFormat=json"

# resize the map to the correct coordinate system (Amersfoort RD/New; 28992)
gdf = gpd.read_file(map_source).to_crs("EPSG:4326")

# generate some random knotweed sightings,  question doesn't have this data...
# some will be outside bounds of geometry
df_knotweed = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        d: np.random.uniform(*gdf.total_bounds[b], 20000)
        for d, b in zip(["lon", "lat"], [[0, 2], [1, 3]])
    }
)

# spatial join polygons to sightings,  then aggregate to get counts
gdf2 = (
    gdf.sjoin(
        gpd.GeoDataFrame(
            geometry=df_knotweed.loc[:, ["lon", "lat"]].apply(
                shapely.geometry.Point, axis=1
            ),
            crs="EPSG:4326",
        ),
        how="left",
    )
    .groupby(level=0)
    .agg({**{c: "first" for c in gdf.columns}, **{"index_right": "count"}})
    .rename(columns={"index_right": "count"})
)

# visualize
px.choropleth_mapbox(
    gdf2,
    geojson=gpd.GeoSeries(gdf2["geometry"]).__geo_interface__,
    locations=gdf2.index,
    color="count",
    hover_data=[c for c in gdf2.columns if c not in ["geometry"]]
).update_layout(
    mapbox={
        "style": "carto-positron",
        "center": {
            "lon": sum(gdf.total_bounds[[0, 2]]) / 2,
            "lat": sum(gdf.total_bounds[[1, 3]]) / 2,
        },
        "zoom":6
    }
)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I do get some errors when running the code. When I run it, I get the error 'spatial indexes require either `rtree` or `pygeos`, even though I instill retree and/or pygeos. Also, apparently 'px.choropleth_mapbox' is a syntax error, even tho to me it looks correct. Do I need to provide our dataframe maybe?

Comment: try `import rtree print(rtree.__version__)`. I'm using 0.9.7,  plotly 5.4.0.  make sure you have restarted your kernel (if using jupyter) after installs

Comment: thank you! We solved this error. We had to install conda however, took 
a long time, but it worked. We have nice map now!